# Error when compile .proto file using wire protocol buffer compiler

Tags: java, compilation, buffer, protocols, protocol-buffers

I am new to use wire protocol buffer. I have PersonProto.proto file:

```
message Person {
  required int32 id = 1;
  required string name = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

and wire-compiler-1.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar in the same folder: Desktop\Newfolder.
I use this command to build:

```
$java -jar wire-compiler-1.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar \ --proto_path=../Newfolder \ --java_out=../Newfolder PersonProto.proto
```

And I got an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\Newfolder (Access is denied)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.squareup.wire.IO$FileIO.parse(IO.java:43)
  at com.squareup.wire.WireCompiler.compile(WireCompiler.java:251)
  at com.squareup.wire.WireCompiler.main(WireCompiler.java:188)
```

I had try with other folder, but I cann't compile successful.
Please give me some ideas,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure from where you are running it has NewFolder as parent? And you are on windows (as i see $ i am assuming its *nix based OS so you should use "/" provided NewFolder exists as parent)?

Comment: Yes, I create Newfolder on Desktop and put Person.proto and wire-compiler-1.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar in it. I am using windows 7.

Comment: I think my folder directory is correct, because I had copied it from folder properties, but I get the same problem

Comment: "I create Newfolder on Desktop and put Person.proto and wire-compiler-1.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar in it" So you are not using ../NewFolder/wire-compiler-1.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar which means you are running your command from NewFolder?

Comment: yes, I run cmd.exe from Newfolder and use that command to compile. You mean there is a problem with my directory?

Comment: I had found how to resolve my problem, just rewrite the command without character "\". It worked good.